Vanilla interface implementations. What should I call it?
Some may think I'm kidding, but I'm really stuck on this
Suppose you have some UserDao interface that you want to implement
What should you call it?
Here are a few points I'd like to make

I firmly believe a subtype's name should end with the supertype name (perhaps, trimmed a bit if it's long). UserDaoImpl is not an option: it's not a subtype of Impl
SimpleUserDao is not a good pick too. It may be "simple" today, not as simple tomorrow
BasicUserDao is also problematic (though, it's my current pick): it's too similar to BaseUserDao which strongly implies the class is abstract (BaseX is generally reserved for abstract classes meant to be subclassed). My implementation is not abstract

Typically, you base your naming on some characteristic features of your type. However, there are no features at all, it's a "vanilla" implementation that communicates with a relational database in the most boring, straightforward way imaginable. There's no way we're going to ever use fancy no-SQL data stores so RelationalUserDao or something to that effect would raise a few eyebrows in my team, for sure
We don't use an ORM framework. Also, our DAO implementations are not coupled to any particular RDBMS (same implementations can hit both Oracle and Postgres DBs)
So what should I do?

That's a Java problem. In the .Net world, the interface would have been called IUserDao, so an implementation can be called UserDao. To be fair, the I prefix brings its own set of issues.

See Interface naming in Java on Stackoverflow (which was closed as being too opinionated, so don't be astonished when this happens to this question again).

Are these classes in the same package? If not, naming both UserDao seems fine, the package will tell you what you're dealing with.

What is the mock implementation of UserDao called? Mine would probably be something like MemoryUserDao (with the "real" implementation being something like SqlUserDao if getting data from a RDBMS, or JsonUserDao if we're storing our users in JSON files).

I took the freedom to add a Java tag (and two more), since this question is definitely dependend on the language ecosystem.

I think my challenge comes from the fact that there's only one implementation. How do you see any features if there's nothing to compare it to?

If there's actually only one implementation, just remove the interface. It adds no value.

...which makes way for a broader question: do you even need an interface if there's only one implementation?

@PhilipKendall you beat me to it

@PhilipKendall however, that feels wrong

@PhilipKendall Usually the response to that is that it's needed for testing, and I think there might be something to that in lieu of invasive tooling.  I personally hate seeing 1-to-1 interface-class pairs, though.

You might be interested in reading Do I need to use an interface when only one class will ever implement it? - it might be relevant to your current conundrum.

And also Why should I use an interface when there is only one implementation class?. In general, search "interfaces with only one implementation" using your favorite search engine will get you lots of information related to this question, but might not answer the question.

"It may be "simple" today, not as simple tomorrow" - not if tomorrow you make a different class that possibly reuses the simple one internally (perhaps after it was suitably evolved to support that). We often let existing code become bloated too easily by defaulting to adding stuff in. Also, try to design so that renaming the class is not a major undertaking. If it "communicates with a relational database in the most boring, straightforward way imaginable", then it looks like it's a CRUD component, so one option is CrudUserDao.

That said, if "communicates with a relational database in the most boring, straightforward way imaginable" (i.e. CRUD) relates to how the class is used by its consumers, then it is actually a statement about the interface (how you want to access data), so it's probably a better name for the interface itself, and then you're back to a slightly worse version of the original problem, with an extra word that you have to use as a suffix due to your naming convention. One option to deal with that is to make use of namespaces (User.CrudDao and User.SqlCrudDao).

While I think this is fundamentally opinion-based, here is how I would approach the problem.

Typically, you base your naming on some characteristic features of your type.

You are on the right track. Keep going...

However, there are no features at all, it's a "vanilla" implementation that communicates with a relational database in the most boring, straightforward way imaginable.

Juuuuuuuust missed it. It communicates with a relational database. Think in terms of this characteristic. Which database? Are you using an ORM, and if so, which ORM? Some options to consider:

HibernateUserDao — assuming you are using Hibernate ORM. You could easily replace it with the name of a different ORM.

OracleUserDao — assuming you are using an Oracle database. Again, you could easily replace it with a different database to get the same effect.

UserDaoImpl because Java. And that's how the community does things. Consider it a quirk or idiom of the people who use the language. This is my least favorite option, but I can't think of a Java developer that would misunderstand it. The Principle of Least Astonishment can be your guide, worst case scenario.


Really, naming based on some characteristic of the type is usually a good strategy. The challenge is thinking that this type is "vanilla" and therefore has no characteristics. I would flip the idea around: the UserDao interface is "vanilla". What characteristic of the implementation adds flavor? It doesn't need to be something exceptional. It can be as simple as DatabaseUserDao.
Jory Geerts, in a comment on the question, also has good advice. If the interface and implementing class are in different packages, use the same name!
Often times the hardest part of naming things is to not over-think the name.

We don't use an ORM framework. Also, our DAO implementations are not coupled to any particular RDBMS (same implementations can hit both Oracle and Postgres DBs)

"If the interface and implementing class are in different packages, use the same name!" Absolutely not. It would be confusing. No-one would bother checking the types' fully-qualified names

Thank you for you input anyway

There is no good way to resolve this naming issue. You need to pick a characteristic - even a small one - and use that in the name of the implementation. Name it after whatever library or database driver you are using: DatabaseDriverNameGoesHereUserDao. Something. I agree that using the same name might be confusing.

@SergeyZolotarev What's the purpose of the interface then? What are the possible implementers?

@Alexander the purpose is doing things SOLIDly and providing a way to switch to a new behavior without changing an existing class or the API that is being relied on (in line with the Open/Closed principle)

If it's just a POJO of data, there is no behaviour. There's nothing to be swapped out. There's nothing SOLID about that, one way or another.

@SergeyZolotarev: I think what Alenxander is getting at is if this interface just belongs to the application and there is literally one and only one implementation, then don't use an interface. This changes, however, if you want to write unit tests for code that needs access to data. Then you have two implemenations of the DAO interface: the database implementation, and a mock or stub for testing purposes.

@GregBurghardt Mockito doesn't care if the mocked dependency is an interface or a class, though. No-one actually writes test doubles nowadays (I don't think it's a bad thing)

@Alexander sorry, I don't get you. It's the DAO itself that should be swappable, like any other injected dependency. Classes should depend on contracts, not details. Classes are merely details of how a certain contract is fulfilled. Or, if I put it a SOLID way, "high-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions". If you believe I'm misinterpreting the dependency inversion principle, feel free to correct me

@SergeyZolotarev: if Mockito does not distinguish between classes and interfaces, then Alexander's point becomes even more relevant. Besides a nebulous "best practice", when tangible benefit does the interface give you right now? Maybe you don't really need the interface, rendering this question moot.

@SergeyZolotarev I do believe you're misunderstanding the principle. You're following the letter of the law, but not its spirit. Inverting dependencies with interfaces isn't done for its own sake, it's done in pursuit of a generally-worth-while goal: to make it easier to swap in implementations. But that only makes sense in a context where multiple possible implementations are even possible. For example, you could abstract Math.sqrt() behind an interface, but that wouldn't make sense: there's only 1 sensible implementation of sqrt(), and it's Math.sqrt(). Likewise, you're using...

... plain old Java objects here to act as DAOs. These are just dumb containers of data, with no behaviour. The contract you're trying to extract into an interface is the exact contract the current class adheres to, and there's no reasonable alternative implementation that could possibly exist. There's no point doing anything in pursuit of modularizing it and making it replaceable, because you have nothing to replace it with. This is why Greg was talking about ORMs. Different impls for different DBs would be an example of a reason to consider an interface here, but thats not your case.

@Alexander what do you mean by "DAOs are just containers of data"? They are clearly service classes, behavior is exactly what they were made for. You may be confusing the abbreviation with another one, "DTO" (which are "dumb data containers with no behavior")

"Absolutely not. It would be confusing. No-one would bother checking the types' fully-qualified names" I think you might be too quick to dismiss this idea.  I would agree if developers are working in notepad or something but who does that? In any decent Java IDE. you can see the qualified name of a type by hovering over it.

@SergeyZolotarev Haha indeed, I was confusing it with DTO :) So can you elaborate on what your DAOs are doing? Are just they just shuttling to/from SQL queries?

@JimmyJames that's what I meant by checking

@Alexander yeah, using an in-house ORM (no, I won't consider naming the class InHouseOrmUserDao, it's an implementation detail that I'm not sure we should keep, frankly)

If you were to change that implementation detail, would you be changing your current DAOs, or would you be making new classes under a new name, which implement the same interface?
